# Cannot connect to MongoDB in Azure

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, azure

I have a MongoDB on Azure and I am trying to connect to it using the npm module [mongodb](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongodb):

```
var mongoClient = require("mongodb").MongoClient;
mongoClient.connect("mongodb://myuser:mypassword@myhost.documents.azure.com:10355/?ssl=true", function (err, db) {
  db.close();
});
```

#### Password

My password has the following characteristics:

- Contains letters, lowercase, uppercase
- No white space
- Contains numbers
- Contains special characters like `=`, `@`, `$` and so on

#### Error

I get the following when executing the code above:

```
Error: Password contains an illegal unescaped character
    at parseConnectionString (C:\Users\myuser\Documents\myproj\node_modules\mongodb\lib\url_parser.js:280:13)
```

However the documentation does not tell much about how to solve this issue. I guess it is an encoding problem. How to fix this?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Characters like @ are restricted as they mess up the structure of the URL. 
 The reason for this is because MongoDB interprets it as the @ separator. Instead of this:

```
var mongoClient = require("mongodb").MongoClient;
mongoClient.connect("mongodb://myuser:myp@ssword@myhost.documents.azure.com:10355/?ssl=true", function (err, db) {
  db.close();
});
```

use this

```
mongoClient.connect("mongodb://myuser:myp%40ssword@myhost.documents.azure.com:10355/?ssl=true", { 
  uri_decode_auth: true 
}, function (err, db) {
  db.close();
});
```

To encode the password, use `encodeURIComponent(password)`

You can also use this syntax.

```
mongoClient.connect("mongodb://myhost.documents.azure.com:10355/?ssl=true", 
 {user: 'username', pass: 'p@ssword'}, function (err, db) {
  db.close();
});
```

On later versions, use

```
auth: {
       user: 'username',
       password: 'p@ssword',
    }
```

as below

```
mongoClient.connect("mongodb://myhost.documents.azure.com:10355/?ssl=true", {
  auth: {
   user: 'username',
   password: 'p@ssword',
  }}, function (err, db) {
  db.close();
});
```

Comment: Thanks! I saw this structure but in posts that were using another library to connect to mongo so i thought the `mongodb` API did not support it! Thanks a bunch

Comment: edit: I edited the post - after testing turns out the syntax was wrong :(

Comment: Please consider putting in your answer the previous syntax. It did work for me. Why did you remove it?

Comment: Sure, will do so.

Comment: Thank you very much. Now it is a complete answer :)

Comment: Don't work with package mongodb version > 3.0.0 see my answer

Answer (score 2):

The accepted answer dont work for me on mongodb > 3.0.x

This code work for me :

```
const mongoClient = require("mongodb").MongoClient;

let database = null;


new mongoClient('mongodb://myhost.documents.azure.com:10355/?ssl=true', {
    auth: {
       user: 'username',
       password: 'p@ssword',
    }
}).connect(
    (err, db) => {
      if (err) return console.error(err);
      console.log('Database connected');
      database = db.db('foo'); 
});
```

Answer (score 1):

MongoDB can now use a password with special characters. To do this, add an option to the connection `{ useNewUrlParser: true }`:

```
const MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
const assert = require('assert');

const uri = 'mongodb://mydbname:pa$s;w@rd@mongodb0.example.com:27017/admin';

MongoClient.connect(uri, { useNewUrlParser: true }, (err, db) => {
    assert.strictEqual(null, err);
    // ...
    db.close();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually, There is a seperate username for mongoDB and for a database..They have a different passwords too..So, make sure you have